service_worker Seems to have been uninstalled
I developed a Chrome browser extension and converted it to a Safari iOS browser extension through xcrun. I found that when running the plugin in Safari on iOS, it runs for about 5 minutes continuously. After manually locking the screen, then opening and refreshing the page, I noticed that the service_worker seemed to have been uninstalled. I tried sending a message to it through chrome.runtime.sendMessage, where the service_worker simply returns a fixed string, but what I received was undefined.
How can I solve this problem?
At first, I mistakenly thought that the cookie was automatically deleted. Then I tried switching to LocalStorage and found the same result. Finally, I discovered that the issue was caused by the content script being unable to communicate with the service worker through runtime.sendMessage. I don't know how to solve it, I searched for a long time but couldn't find an answer.
